# How can I compile this successfully?

Tags: pseudocode

I have to use `algpseudocode` package to improve my paper look like more professional

But I can't compile successfully.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{AIP}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{MyProcedure}{}
\State $\textit{locationAgent} \gets \text{position of }\textit{{agent}}$
\State $\textit{locationMD} \gets \text{position of }\textit{{MD}}$
\If {\textit{distance(eNB,$agent_i$)}}>$\delta$
\BState \emph{loop}:
\State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
\If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$}\Return TURE
\State $j \gets j-1$.
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} loop
\EndProcedure
```

Comment: The code is not compilable, as it is. Please, fill in what's necessary to make it into a full example.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think "how to make this document compilable" is the question.  And my answer would be: learn the basics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing an `\EndIf` somewhere. I inserted one after line 11 of the listing. Just adapt your code to tell the `Procedure`, where the second if-loop is ending.

```
% arara: pdflatex 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{AIP}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{MyProcedure}{}
\State \textit{locationAgent} $\gets$ position of \textit{agent}
\State \textit{locationMD} $\gets$ position of \textit{MD}
\If {\textit{distance(eNB,$agent_i$)} $> \delta$} 
\BState \emph{loop}:
\State $j \gets \textit{patlen}$
\If {$\textit{string}(i) = \textit{path}(j)$} \Return TRUE
\State $j \gets j-1$.
\State $i \gets i-1$.
\State \textbf{goto} \emph{loop}.
\State \textbf{close};
\EndIf % put this command to where it's actually needed!
\EndIf
\State $i \gets i+\max(\textit{delta}_1(\textit{string}(i)),\textit{delta}_2(j))$.
\State \textbf{goto} 
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]